# Having trouble finding all solutions of $\sin^2 x =2\sin x +3$. The answer has the form $A+Bk\pi$ where $k$ is an integer and $0<A<2\pi$.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am working on a homework assignment for an online pre-calculus class, and I am running into trouble trying to learn the steps for solving equations with an answer in this form. The book and course materials don't have any great explanations on how to accomplish this type of problem. I know it has something to do with adding pi n times to a solution that worked, but it is a vague concept to me at this point. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Equation:
$\sin^2 x=2\sin x+3$

Comment: The period of $\sin x$ is $2\pi$, so you will have to add $2n\pi$ to any solutions in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin^2x=2\sin x+3$

$\sin^2x-2\sin x-3=0$

$(\sin x-3)(\sin x+1)=0$

Either $\sin x-3=0$ or $\sin x+1=0$

$\sin x=3$ is impossible so no solution for this case

next, $\sin x+1=0\implies \sin x=-1 \implies x=\frac {3\pi}{2}+2n\pi$

Answer (score 0):

Since for all real $x$ we have

$$-1\le\sin x\le1$$

then the Lhs of the equation is at most $1$ and the Rhs is at least $3-2=1$, so the only solution is when both sides equal $1$, and $\sin x=-1$, so

$$x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to notice that: $f_1(x)=\sin^2(x)\in[0,1]$ and that $f_2(x)= 2\sin(x)+3\in[1,5]$.

So there is only one point that satisfies $f_1(x) = f_2(x) = 1$, then you can solve for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\sin^2(x)-2\sin(x)-3=(\sin(x)+1)(\sin(x)-3)$$